# spark scala dataframes - create an object with attributes in a json file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a json file of the format

```
{"x1": 2, "y1": 6, "x2":3, "y2":7}
```

I have a scala class

```
class test(int:x, int:y)
```

Using spark I am trying to read this file and create two test objects for each line from the json file. for example

```
{"x1": 2, "y1": 6, "x2":3, "y2":7} should create 
test1 = new test(2,6) and     
test2 = new test(3,7)
```

Then for each line of the json file, i want to call a function that takes two test objects as parameters. Example callFunction(test1,test2)

How do i do this with spark. I see method that will convert rows in json file to list of objects but no way to create multiple objects using attributes in a single row of json file

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Example")
  .setMaster("local")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

val coordinates = sqlContext.read.json("c:/testfile.json")

//NOT SURE HOW TO DO THE FOLLOWING
//test1 = new Test(attr1 of json file, attr2 of json file)
//test2 = new Test(attr3 of json file, attr4 of json file)
//callFunction(test1,test2)
//collect the result of callFunction
```

Comment: I tried to do a coordinates.select but that gives you an array of a specific attribute, Tried to use an iterator over dataframes, but that defeats the purpose of using spark

Comment: @user373201: why dont you pass the entire JSON record to callFunction(df), then you can do your logic inside callFunction and return it in the way you want.

Comment: I am new to spark. my aim is to parallelize the computation inside callFunction to records in json file. If I read the entire json file in callFunction, what would i be parallizing?